# How can I drop into the Perl 6 REPL inside a program?

Tags: debugging, raku

Is there a way that I can single step through part (or all) of a Perl 6 program? I expected that there would be a `-d`, but of course there is not:

```
% perl6 -d test.p6
```

I thought perhaps eval-ing the file, but that does the whole thing at once:

```
% perl 6
> EVALFILE 'test.p6'
```

As I expected, that just runs the entire file.

I suspect someone hasn't implemented this sort of thing. Is there some way I can hook into the runtime to insert actions between statements and so on? In Perl 5 land, that would be the `DB` class.

Aside from that, does Perl 6 work with any general debuggers? If I were using the JVM backend, would it even make sense to use a Java tool (or is it gibberish by that point)?

Comment: there's a separate `perl6-debug` executable which requires the `Debugger::UI::CommandLine` module, though historically, it's been known to break from time to time

Comment: Ah, Rakudo Star has a `perl6-debug-m`, which I think means it's for `moar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started working on this problem as one of the features of [LREP](https://github.com/awwaiid/p6-lrep). I haven't worked on it for a while, so not sure how well it still works. Since the last time I worked on LREP, we've done a lot of cleanup on the internal REPL–I hope to modify LREP to work more cleanly and add in debugger features.

Comment: I come from February, 2018 and it not only works, it's a life changer for Perl6 n00bs! Thank you.